# How to set URLSchemes for facebook ios sdk

Tags: ios, facebook-ios-sdk, url-scheme

I've spent a whole day on this issue and didn't find any good answer after hours of googling and debugging. I've finally solved the problem and I will share it here.

The documentation for setting up facebook-ios-sdk shows how to set up a url scheme that is used to return the user to your app after authorization. Something like fb12087732691...

Unfortunately, they are using an older version of Xcode and the graphic looks like this:

[image]

What it really should be, using Xcode 4+, is this:

[image]

Hope this saves someone a few hours of their life!!!

Comment: nice info, but it'd be more appropriate if you've asked the problem in a question style, then answered it as an answer to that question. that's how this site works.

Answer (score 0):

There's a **AppName-Info.plist** file in your project. Open it and you will find the similar stuff. It's universal for Xcode4+ (as far as I know).